# AWS copilot on Cloud9 InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid (status code: 403)

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-cloud9

On Execution of command below from AWS Cloud9

```
copilot app delete
```

Getting message as :

```
 execute svc delete: delete service: delete stack demoappone-test-lbdemoappone: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid
        status code: 403, request id: 5001e2d0-3bbc-4821-911c-27713af4f2f9
```

AWS Cloud9 points to document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/welcome.html .

Do we know how to solve above 403 error?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be because Cloud9 has a limited set of allowed actions that're supported for [AWS managed temporary credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/security-iam.html#auth-and-access-control-temporary-managed-credentials-supported). (For the troubleshooting guide: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-cli-invalid-token))

The way that the ECS workshop gets around it is by creating and storing access credentials in the environment: [sample solution](https://ecsworkshop.com/microservices/software/). (For the Cloud9 guide: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/credentials.html#credentials-permanent-create))